# Getting TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not tuple when searching in DB

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

Could you please help a noobie.
I'm getting this error when trying to search and display data from database in my GUI.
'''

```
 search_box = Entry(search_products)
    search_box_get = search_box.get()
    search_box_get = str(search_box_get)

   def search_product_name():
        connection = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        # selects everything from the table called Products
        sql = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE product_name=?", search_box_get

        all_rows = cursor.execute(sql)

        for record in table.get_children():
            table.delete(record)

        for i in all_rows:
            table.insert('', 'end', values=i)
        connection.commit()
```

'''

That's the error I'm getting

```
    all_rows = cursor.execute(sql)
TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not tuple
```

Answer (score 1):

`sql` is a tuple but `cursor.execute()` requires a SQL string and a tuple/list arguments.

Also you should get the content of `search_box` inside `search_product_name()`:

```py
def search_product_name():
    search_box_get = search_box.get()

    connection = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name = ?"
    all_rows = cursor.execute(sql, [search_box_get])
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you sir!!!! You really helped me. Have a good day :)